# How to get keypress if press a key anywhere in the document?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fire keypress event anytime and anywhere I hit *enter*, but I only can reach this in specifying in a DOM element with ng-keypress.

I reached this result using pure javascript with this code:

```
document.onkeydown = function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
      //do something
    }
}
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way, or the "angular way" to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wrap it in a directive and go from there, example:

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("keypressDetector", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            document.onkeydown = function(e){
                if(e.keyCode === 13){
                    //do something
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

And use it:

```
<body keypress-detector></body>
```

Answer (score 2):

**To invoke a function on your nested controller...**

You can use the built-in `ng-keypress` directive on the `<body>` tag:

```
<body ng-keypress="enterKeyPressed($event)">
```

That can be bound to a function on `$rootScope` from your module's `run()` block:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.enterKeyPressed = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("EnterKeyPressed");
    }
  };
});
```

That raises an event that can be picked up using `$scope` from within your controller:

```
$scope.$on("EnterKeyPressed", function() {
  vm.incrementCounter();
});
```

**Demo**

[**CodePen: Using ng-keypress with an event**](https://codepen.io/mjcwly/pen/veKEoX/)

Comment: @William I've updated my answer to reflect the fact that your controller is nested within (and not on) the body tag.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using AngularJS, you should [ng-keydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown) on your outter-most HTML element.

For example:

```
<body ng-keydown="myKeyDownFunction($event)"></body>

$scope.myKeyDownFunction = function($event) {
    if($event.keycode === 13) {
         // Do what you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: My controller is inside the body tag, and when I put it inside the first <div> in controller, it doesn't works.